# How to fix: user inputted string not working correctly as a function

Tags: c

I have a successfully written encryption code that asks the user if they want a left shift or right shift and how much they want to shift by.The goal is to make the program work through functions. I was able to get the first part of the code into a function (school programming exercise), but I am stuck on getting the user input. The function is getValidMessage(); I know I've called it correctly in the main code. I think the issue might be with null terminating the string, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

I have a line of code that should null-terminate it, and I think I made enough changes to the original code that it should work. However, I'm not sure that I implemented the code correctly in the function.

```
// get message to encrypt
//This is called in the main function
char originalMessage[100];
getValidMessage(&originalMessage, sizeof(originalMessage));
int originalMessageLength = strnlen(originalMessage, 
sizeof(originalMessage));


//This is the function
/*
* Gets valid message from user
*/
void getValidMessage(char* message, int messageSize)
{
     char originalMessage[100];
     bool validMessage = false;
     printf("\n");
     printf("Enter message to be encrypted (upper case alphabetic 
     characters only): ");
     fgets(originalMessage, messageSize, stdin);
     int originalMessageLength = strnlen(originalMessage, 
     messageSize) - 1;
     while (!validMessage)
     {
         // invalid if non-upper case alpha characters in 
         // message (don't include newline at end))
         validMessage = true;
         for (int i = 0; i < originalMessageLength; i++)
         {
             if (!isupper(originalMessage[i]))
             {
                 printf("\n");
                 printf("Message must contain only upper "
                 "case alphabetic characters!\n");
                 printf("Enter message to be encrypted "
                 "(upper case alphabetic characters only):");
                 fgets(originalMessage, messageSize, stdin);
                 originalMessageLength = 
                 strnlen(originalMessage, messageSize) - 1;

                 // reset flag and exit for loop
                 validMessage = false;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     originalMessage[originalMessageLength] = '\0';
     return originalMessage;
}
```

I am using a running test code that uses MESSAGE. The entirety of the code should encrypt and decrypt the code to show OGUUCIG and then MESSAGE again. Currently, it just shows a bunch of weird characters. 
Note: This is NOT the entirety of the code. It doesn't show the encryption or decryption code. I know that works fine, but I can't get it to work smoothly with a separate function instead of in the main body of the code.

Comment: Something like `&originalMessage` is suspect, especially when `originalMessage` is an array. The type of `&originalMessage` is `char (*)[100]`, which is very much different from what `getValidMessage` expects. Remember that array natrually decays to pointers to their first element, i.e. plain `originalMessage` is equal to `&originalMessage[0]` which both are of type `char *`.

Comment: And how do you `return originalMessage` from a function declared to not return anything? And are the comments broken into two lines in the original code as well? Please don't do manual word-wrap when posting code, create a [mcve] and then copy-paste it as-is.

Comment: Please take more care with indenting and formatting your code, i.e. I agree with Some. I fixed it now and hope that I did not break anything; otherwise please accept my apology and [edit] to fix whatever I broke.

Comment: HI Tirzah Blazis, I would actually be interested in learning how exactly you copied the code to the question. The queer way of accumulating indentation and the syntax-breaking linewrappings must have an error-source in that way of copying. Please understand that I really want your help on this. Understanding how this happened would allow me to better help users with the same problem in the future. So please write a comment on your own question (you can, you know), which includes "@Yunnosch" and describes what you did. I would really appreciate that and  pay back by helping as much as I can.